# Best practice for database methods in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, data-access-layer

I am pretty new to MVC 4, and I have worked mostly with web forms up to this moment in C#. I understand the pattern of MVC, the routing, calling actions and so on.

But what about the actions which are responsible for fetching data from the database, for example by firing stored procedures? I have seen some tutorials where they put the logic for connecting to the database directly in the actions.

However I am thinking of a more centralized way to do it. For example, I can put all the functions which are firing stored procedures in a separate class named DatabaseCoordinator.cs in a folder named Helpers for example. Then I can call them from the actions in the controllers.

In that way I will know that I can find all of my methods for the database in one class, which is a very clean solution, I think (or at least in web forms). However I want to follow the pattern of MVC, and use only models, views and controllers as the name of the pattern itself implies.

So what is the best practice for that? Should I make a separate class for this, or implement the logic directly in the controllers, or perhaps somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should certainly make a separate repository class to contain all of your data access operations.

There is a good worked example here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you put your data access code somewhere other than in your controller.  The controller's primary purpose is to gather together the information for display on a page or the reverse - to take the data from the page that is posted back and feed it to the code responsible for business rules and data access.

For most MVC projects (heck, for most projects really!) I build separate class library projects - at minimum one for business rules and data access, though typically I'll make those two separate projects.  The purpose of separating the logic is really for simpler future maintenance and reusability.  If you keep your various logical parts separate, you can easily swap them out if your logic or database needs to change, or you can easily consume the business rules and data from a new type of user interface; for example, if you decided to implement your project as a Windows forms application in addition to your web system, you could (theoretically) just reuse your business logic and data access logic libraries and only rebuild the user layer.  However, if you build your logic into your controller, you really can't reuse that logic without extracting it and converting it to the new application model you're using.

So, simply put, definitely keep 99% of your logic and data access out of your controller.  Only put what you must put into your controller, the rest in a separate class, or where appropriate, in separate class libraries.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The `Controllers` and `Views` tend to stay within the same project, but it's common to split the `data access classes` and `models` into their own seperate `class library`, as this allows other projects to utilise them.

This will allow you, in the future, to maybe add a windows forms/wpf interface or maybe a mobile device interface, leveraging the work you already have in the standalone class library.

Another thing to consider, is looking into how to use `ViewModels` in your MVC application. It's a common technique when Views require more than one `domain object`. [Using View Models in MVC](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/).

Comment: Does this answer still reflect your preferences? And, if so, what do you generally name the data access class library? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Unit of Work Pattern (UOW) combined with the Repository Pattern. It doesn't matter if you ultimately call a stored procedure or an inline linq query to return results, your caller shouldn't know or care how GetPersons is ultimately implemented. The UOW pattern combined with the Repository pattern is a very popular way to expose an Entity Framework database in the ASP.NET community. You will find different ways to do it, some are over-kill and some just create dependencies with no actual benefit but you will find a way that feels right to you with those patterns.

Answer (score 1):

After more experience, I would like to change my answer and state that the Repository Pattern and thus the Unit of Work pattern are pointless layers of abstraction to prevent you from working with Entity Framework, which is your data layer abstraction! directly.

Other than being able to swap out databases from say Microsoft SQL PostgreSQL (when would this ever happen in the real world?) and control the structure of complex queries that you don't want repeated in your code, I see no real value to the repository pattern. To include CreatedBy,ModifiedBy values on Insert/Update you need only override EntityFramework. To encapsulate queries that include business rules such as where active = 1 and isdeleted = 0 just extend Linq queries with extension methods.